# How to fill cells from sheet A with values from sheet B when ID matches (in Excel)?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Consider the following 2 sheets. Sheet `AAA` has a list of companies with an emptry column `ROA`. Sheet `BBB` has a `ROA` value for some of these companies.

Sheet `AAA`

```
    A    B
1  ID   ROA
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
```

Sheet `BBB`

```
    A    B
1  ID   ROA
2   1   60.40
3   3   10.10
4   4    9.00
```

Looking at the ID in both sheets, I need a formula to fill in column `AAA.B`, resulting in

```
    A    B
1  ID   ROA
2   1   60.40
3   2
4   3   10.10
5   4    9.00
```

What formula do I need in cell `AAA.B2` (and down) to get this done? I believe `VLOOKUP` is the function appropriate here, but I am unsure as how to use it in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LOOKUP function with MATCH and ISNA:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,0)),"",LOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3))
```